# Short story about a monster trapped behind an invisible wall in the forest

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I'm searching for a short story that I read at my local public library in the early 80's.

There was a "monster" who was trapped behind an invisible wall in the forest. The only way it could escape/die was if it lured someone into the walled area who would then take its place.

I'm pretty sure the story was part of a collection of scary stories for kids.

Comment: Make it a ship and you've got the Flying Dutchman.  :-)